# creating subrecords in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

my territory model

```
class Territory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :publisher
  has_many :addresses, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
end
```

my address model

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :street, :district, :note
  belongs_to :territory
end
```

I have a form for creating territories and a view to show a singe territory.

I've added a form for adding addresses to territories to the territory show view.

This is my address controller

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @address = Address.new
  end

  def create
    @address = territory.addresses.build(params[:address])

    if @address.save
      flash[:success] = "Address saved!"
      redirect_to '/territories'
    else
      redirect_to '/territories'
    end
  end
end
```

It looks that I can't get hold of the id of the current territory, hence can't connect the address to the territory. How can I do that?

Also, after the save I'd like to show the current view, i.e. a territory show view again. Not show how to do this redirect...

my routes

```
TerritoryManagement::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :addresses
  resources :territories
end
```

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested resources for this, which is explained in the [official Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). Another great example of this nested resources is in the [official Getting Started Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html).

With this, you should receive a `params[:territory_id]` variable in your `AddressesController` when you make a new address for that territory, and from that you can then find the `Territory` by doing this:

```
Territory.find(params[:territory_id])
```

But rather than me repeating it here, I would really recommend you read both those guides.

Comment: I've changed my routes.rb to TerritoryManagement::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :territories do
    resources :addresses
  end
end
however now it says it's looking /addresses and can't find it. From the guide you pointed to I understand that this would add all necessery routes. I have completely no idea what I'm missing.

Comment: in my list of territories I have a link to show a specific territory <td><%= link_to 'Show', territory_address_path(@territory, @address) %></td> When I call that list then I get No route matches {:controller=>"addresses", :action=>"show"} Sorry, I just don't get it.

Comment: @Thomas: I would really *really* recommend going through the Getting Started guide example and going along with that. That should give you enough of a basic understanding to translate it across to what you want to do here. It's basically the same thing, but with different names.